# How to solve a "Variable 'args' is accessed from within inner class" Java error?

Tags: java, syntax-error

The Java class quoted below uses three numerical values. I want to call this class from command line passing different values each time through the args variable. But when I do that, I get a "Variable 'args' is accessed from within inner class" Java error. What's the most efficient way - if any - to accomplish my goal?

```
class UserBaseRecommenderEvaluation {

    private UserBaseRecommenderEvaluation() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("/home/eualin/Downloads/ml-100k/final.data"));

        RecommenderBuilder builder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) throws TasteException {
                UserSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);
                UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(2, similarity, model);
                return new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
            }
        };

        RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator evaluator = new GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator();
        IRStatistics stats = evaluator.evaluate(builder,
                null,
                model,
                null,
                1,
                GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.CHOOSE_THRESHOLD,
                1);        
    }     
}
```

**UPDATE:** As a further step, how could I make the above function work within a for loop that assigns a different value to each of these parameters? In this case, keep in mind that there is also a need to deal with error handling otherwise the execution will be terminated unexpectedly as some of the combinations will be not 'appropriate'.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see `args` referenced at all.

Comment: Yeah, actually I am asking how to do that with args...

Comment: Your last edit makes this question a little inappropriate for the site. Why don't you go ahead and try and solve that issue yourself and return here if you can't figure out an answer? Post a new question if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wishing to just access values from the `args` parameter, just specify it as `final`. The example below will compile and run just nicely:

```
public class InnerClassExample {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {        
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
      }
    };

    runnable.run();
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: It looks like `model` is passed in as an argument, not used in Java's odd closure-way.  As such, it shouldn't need to be `final`.

Comment: @cHao Oh yes, that's not going to work...

Comment: @DuncanJones Which of the above is not going to work? This "Or just declare your args parameter as final." is not working in my case for sure! Apart from that, if you don't mind, please see the update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @cHao If you don't mind, please see the update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @eualin See my comments below the horizontal rule in my answer. It will *compile*, but you may not be referring to the `model` you think you are.

Comment: No, I am not referring to the `model` variable. In fact, I am referring to the three numerical values; 2,1,1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't finish the error message :) "Needs to be declared final".

In order to fix this, you need to declare all variables that are accessed inside your inner class `final`. So, for `main` it would be:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) { ... }
```

Comment: This simply doesn't work in my case. Apart from that, please see the update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: This must be the right answer, based on your other comments. Explain why it "*doesn't work*"?